# Will a To-5 kickstart cap for 1 to 3 ton units possibly be able to help a 4 ton unit compressor start at all? Ri

Tags: capacitor

Will a T0-5 kickstart capacitor be strong enough to help start a 4 ton unit?

Comment: I already have one of those caps is why I ask.  My compressor usually starts in the evening,  but won't start once the day warms up in the morning.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is far too detailed and commercial for the Home Improvement site. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves commercial A/C equipment.

Comment: I've seen questions about 5-ton residential units here, so I'm not sure how the determination was made that this is for commercial equipment. Unless a "T0-5 kickstart capacitor" is only used on commercial equipment, in which case #TIL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call an HVAC company to have that A/C unit serviced. It sounds as if the compressor may need attention, the existing capacitors are in need of replacing, or the unit has been grossly overcharged. Any of the above could cause the condition that you mention. Do not add any "starting kit" until the unit has been serviced by a competent service company. If there is a problem with the unit you cannot fix it by adding a kickstart capacitor.